# When do I use PDO::query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Much have been written about the benefits of using [`PDO::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), but little has been written on the benefits of using [`PDO::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php). I believe `PDO::query` is created to serve a purpose and there ought to be some relative advantage of using this function over `PDO::prepare`.

I have a query that goes like this:

```
SELECT * from Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

This query contains no user input for escaping and no variables for repeated querying. Should I use `PDO::query`, go back to `mysqli_query` or stick to `PDO::prepare` in this case?

**UPDATE**: Further examination on the general query log shows this for both `PDO::prepare` and `PDO::query`:

```
22 Connect user@localhost on Database
22 Prepare SELECT * from Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
22 Execute SELECT * from Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
22 Close stmt   
22 Quit
```

I was expecting `PDO::query` to produce:

```
22 Connect user@localhost on Database
22 Query SELECT * from Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
22 Quit
```

But this only happens, and to both, when `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true)`. I am quite surprised at the result that I am getting. It seems that `PDO::query` generates prepared statements as well.

Comment: Do you need this very query once, or multiple times? (Binding parameters is only a secondary purpose of the prepare/execute pair.)

Comment: @mario: this query is executed once in the script.

Comment: great observation. PDO is like a black box, always nice to see some light shed on it's internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need it once, then there's no point in creating a prepared statement (which unless emulated would result in two network transmissions to the database). Much less so when there are no variable parameters to be bound.

`PDO::query` is not about benefits. Its use comes with the absence of any. One-off queries don't benefit from the potential speed advantage of prepared statements.

Comment: do he need to use any escape functions to filter the data? to prevent sql injection?

Comment: Yes. There's no automatic escaping or anything. It's basically the equivalent of `mysql_query`.

Comment: @mario: If there is no benefits, which option would you choose and why?

Comment: @BenHuh: Using a wrapper function, all my queries are prepared. I wouldn't bother with `::query` unless profiling advises to. (And I probably don't have any queries that don't depend on parameters. If there's no relation or anything, it might not even belong into the DB.)

Comment: @mario, though the query is executed once per script run, the script itself can be executed several thousand times per day. Would preparing the statement helps at all?

Comment: @Ben nope. to use the same query you have to pass the PDO object between different PHP instances which is not possible, makes no sense and gains you no benefits anyway.

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel: Thanks for the response. I am seeing some light finally :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess I have missed it completely. It states in the PHP manual for `PDO::query` that:

```
PDOStatement PDO::query ( string $statement )
```

## Parameters

### statement

> The SQL statement to prepare and execute.

What this means is that the SQL statement is prepared *even* with `PDO::query`. Therefore there is absolutely no advantage to use `PDO::query` except saving a line or two on the PHP script. This is verified by the general query log shown in the question above.

Comment: As Mario said, in every sane PHP script there would be no raw PDO calls anyway but calls to some db access library. So, in fact you cannot save even these 2 lines really :)